# I keep getting "The following module(s) were not installed properly"

Tags: module, installation, prestashop

I installed `prestashop` successfully through `your marketplace`, and been able to play around with it and also to upload new modules. But every time i try to install the uploaded modules, i get this message

> "The following module(s) were not installed properly:"

But the prestashop default modules do install without issues.

What is causing that problem? because the same modules were uploaded and installed without issues on cpanel shared web hosting?

Answer (score 1):

Check modules sql commands for installation. I think module has an character issue. if u enable debugmode and display errors on config/defines.inc.php u can see where the error is. 
If u cant solve. 
Find this line on your module main php ( for "testmodule" its "testmodule.php") "if (!DB::getInstance()->execute(trim($query))) return false;" some think like that. And remove or close this line. But when u doing this u must manualy run modules sql code with phpmyadmin or something else after or before install module.

modules sql files usualy "install.sql" but some this coders add sql code on modules main phps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error and means that your module installation has failed.